# Simple fetch and display using IPFS - CORS issue

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api, ipfs

I'm attempting to fetch the following image hosted on IPFS, and present it dynamically in a webpage:

https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcRD4wkPPi6dig81r5sLj9Zm1gDCL4zgpEj9CfuRrGbzF

I've got the following:

```html
    <html>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https: ;script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
<head>

<script>

let url = new URL("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcRD4wkPPi6dig81r5sLj9Zm1gDCL4zgpEj9CfuRrGbzF")
;(async function(){
let a = await fetch(url)
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = a.data
})()
</script>

<style>
  #container {
    background-color: green;
    width:100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox/chrome give the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcRD4wkPPi6dig81r5sLj9Zm1gDCL4zgpEj9CfuRrGbzF. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)

**Does the "Same Origin Policy" in this error refer to the settings on the server or in the browser?**

*N.b. [this resource](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/) (https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/) seems to imply that CORS requests should work on the ipfs.io server.*

**What is the most simple way to fetch and display an image from a remote IPFS node, solely in the browser?**

Edit: I've managed to get something partially working, based on the examples at [js.ipfs.io](https://js.ipfs.io/).

I still get CORS errors, but it does pull one chunk of text and display it (the image doesn't work still.

Why does this partially work?

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs@0.41.0-rc.2/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script>

async function main() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container')
  let node;
    node = await Ipfs.create({ repo: 'ipfs-' + Math.random()})
  const stream = node.cat('QmPChd2hVbrJ6bfo3WBcTW4iZnpHm8TEzWkLHmLpXhF68A')
  let data = ''

  for await (const chunk of stream) {
    console.log('chunk',chunk)
    data += chunk.toString()
  }
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = data

}
main()
</script>

<style>
  #container {
    background-color: green;
    width:100%;
    width:150px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the browser, to protect from cross site request forgery attacks browsers don't allow requests from one origin(here being your localhost at which your code is running) to another origin(here being the site you are fetching your image from).
To overcome this you have actually 3 ways and a good explanation of all of them can be seen here :https://medium.com/@dtkatz/3-ways-to-fix-the-cors-error-and-how-access-control-allow-origin-works-d97d55946d9

Comment: Thanks, useful link, are you sure this is to do with browser settings? The other answerer says it's server side...

Comment: So basically it’s server side in the sense that server has to respond with headers that tell the browser whether the site you are running on browser can access the data or not. If the server response has headers that contain the site name or allow all format like this : { ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’: ‘*’} .This header means anyone can access resources from server. But at the end the response is checked by the browser only where it checks in header who can access the data and if your origin is not allowed then browser restricts the site or localhost from fetching. For moreclearityreadarticle.

Answer (score 0):

Does the "Same Origin Policy" in this error refer to the settings on the server or in the browser?
yes it does refer to the settings on the server as the headers sent from the server are not set to allow-cross-origin. 
For your request to work you can use a proxy or make your own one on cloudflare  or host it on heroku 
for a quick solution, add this at the beginning of the url
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks, are you sure it's the server side? The other answerer says it's browser side..

Comment: you can verify the headers from the server by checking the  browser=> inspect=> network and you will be able to verify the response from the server

Comment: if  you are using chrome can you deactivate your plugins sometimes a plugin can cause this error